# Finding and splitting frame with contour in video

Tags: python, opencv

Frame from video file
[image: Frame from video file]

I am new to opencv, really appreciate your help.
I am trying to detect the frame number in video file when the contour was detected and trim the video file based on frame [2 frame before the contour was detected and 2 frame after contour].

```
ret, frame=cap.read()
frame[frame<=thresholds]=0
mask = object_detector.apply(frame)
_, mask  = cv2.threshold(mask,254,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)        #mask the backgroubd to the color ratio of 255 for complete black color
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)

for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area>100:    #detect for the flashes above 1000pixel
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [cnt], -1, (0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: Show the image.

Comment: I have added the frame above.

Comment: What is your difficulty? Is your detection non working as expected? Is working as expected, but you do not know which frame is it? You do not know how to cut the video once you detected the frame?

Comment: Yes, I do not know the frame number when the light was detected and to make a video file(trim the video) for 2 frame before the light is detected and 2 frame after the light is detected.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/find-frame-when-contour-was-detected-and-trim-video/9704